# Laravel Auth User API architecture problem

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-sanctum

I ran into a "good practice question" when was trying to wrote an API for an authenticated user.

So, if I'm not writing an SPA, then i need an API for making axios(for example) request to get authenticated user's data. And i got kinda stuck.

If I'll put all user data routes in `web.php`, then my controller will be forced to return JSON for Vue to parse the data, which is not really a good practice for `web.php` routes.

If I'll put all user data routes in `api.php`, then it's a good practice to return JSON from it's controllers, but i won't be able to get an authenticated user simply with `auth()->user()` because `api.php` doesn't use an authenticated user session. So I'm forced to put a damn sanctum token for each of api request, which is a little:

1. annoying
2. not possible when rendering full page with vue
3. might be considered bad practice
4. can be avoided by simply putting all routes to `web.php`

So, what is your opinion on where to put that kind of routes?

Answer (score 0):

If the request you want to make is coming from a session-based authenticated user (you are authenticating your users using regular laravel sessions), then use the `web.php` file.
If it is coming from an API-based authenticated user (you are authenticating your users using API tokens), then use `api.php` file.

It doesn't matter if the data that is going to be returned is JSON data or a blade view, if you are using regular session-based authentication, just use `web.php` file.

I assume you are not writing an API and you want to get the user data from a session-based authenticated user. In this case, you should definitely use `web.php` file for this and it is not a bad practice.

Comment: or use `api.php` to keep them separate but adjust the middleware assigned to them to the `web` group of middleware instead of the `api` group